# How to display content on Mouseover in new row

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code and working fine, except when we do mouseover, contents of Mouseover (in this case edit link) is displaying in same row where brands are availble.

I want this to be displayed in next to next row. (so the brands position wont get disturb).

```
        <div class="row">
            <div ng-repeat="brand in brands">
                <div class="col-sm-1" id="{{ brand.Id }}" ng-mouseover="hoverEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="hoverEdit = false()"> {{brand.Name | makeUppercase }} </div>
                <span ng-show="hoverEdit">
                    <a>Edit</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Can you post your JS or fiddle it please?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the edit fields to be in the next row, use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` so that you can group the data rows together..

```
  <div class="row" ng-repeat-start="brand in brands">
      <div class="col-sm-1" id="{{ brand.Id }}" ng-mouseover="hoverEdit = true" ng-mouseleave="hoverEdit = false()"> {{brand.Name | makeUppercase }}
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" ng-repeat-end="" ng-show="hoverEdit">
       (edit fields here)
  </div>
```

Here's an example with different data: http://bootply.com/ZON3l5BOoM